# Casting for generic EntityFramework Core Expression

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I quite like an IRecordAuthority concept I've seen for filtering records specific identities are allowed to query on an EF DbContext. The interface declare `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Clause<TEntity>() where TEntity : IEntity` and is implemented like this:

```
public class AssignedUserRecordAuthority : IRecordAuthority
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public AssignedUserRecordAuthority(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;

    }

    public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Clause<TEntity>() where TEntity : IEntity
    {
        if (typeof(TEntity) == typeof(Customer))
        {
            var name = _userService.ClaimsIdentity.Name;
            return x => (x as Customer).ManagedBy == name;
        }

        return x => false;
    }
}
```

On my EntityDbContext there's a call which plugs this expression onto every IQueryable request from the context:

```
public new IQueryable<TEntity> Get<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    return Set<TEntity>()
        .AsExpandable()
        .Where(_recordAuthority.Clause<TEntity>());
}
```

The calling code can then tack on the standard Linq for the use case.

The issue I'm facing though is I get this error:

System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (The LINQ expression 'DbSet
.Where(c => (c as Customer).ManagedBy == __name_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.)'

I can only assume that EF is trying to translate the cast which there's no provider for. I'd be surprised if it was the string comparison. So as the various decisions I'll add for each entity type may rely heavily on access to properties on each entity for comparison, can anyone see how I can add a cast step outside the expression which won't fail translation?

The intention of the recordauthority implementations is to build a set of conditions that are expressions for specific entity classes which implement IEntity, to restrict rows the caller is allowed to see. This expression is set prior to the caller's expression and can't be altered by the caller therefore provides row level security which EF doesn't provide out of the box. This class will return x => true at the bottom, for for any entities where there restrictions will be applied an if block checkign for the type of TEntity will be made and within that an expression built to suit. A cast to the specific entity type is required in cases where values on the table need to be compared with know values, such as the logged on username in my example, but it could be anything.

UPDATE:
The full code with a working example is at https://github.com/steveski/Perigee.Framework

Comment: Can you build the expression in a way that it doesn't require access to `_userService`? You might be even just do something like `OfType<Customer>().Where(it => it.ManagedBy == name);`

Comment: You should be able to just return `x => x.ManagedBy == name;`.

Comment: @GertArnold no, becuase x is TEntity, not the multitude of concrete types that will be TEntity. THis recordauthority implementation will have an expression for each type of entity. It's not reasonable to telescope my generic where to be of 100 possible entity types

Comment: You constrain them to `IEntity`. Which I assumed contained `ManagedBy`.

Comment: @Progman THe point is that I need to filter to certain values, so I need the username to compare with the ManagedBy field.

Comment: @GertArnold No IEntity doesn't have managed by. Customer : IEntity has the ManagedBy field

Comment: @StephenYork Depending on how you build/use the filter you can provide the username from "outside" the `Clause()` method. Please [edit] your question to include the remaining classes you have, preferable as a [mcve], to show how you want to use the `Clause()` method and how it should work. That you have a hard cast to `Customer` in your `Clause()` method doesn't look right either. Please elaborate what you are trying to build.

Comment: Then you can't do this. Generics contravariance prohibits it.

Comment: @GertArnold It works absolutely fine in the EF6 example I have seen. This isn't about variance on the generics. It's trying to create a translation on the cast in the EFCore example which is failing

Comment: I've updated my question and provided the source repository. It has a console app example which is where the problem is coming up

Comment: I was thinking ahead. As you observe here, EF core doesn't support your construction, as opposed to EF6. The obvious alternative would be to return typed expressions of which the typed parameter implements `IEntity`. But that's not possible because of contravariance.

Comment: Why is my question downvoted?

Comment: @GertArnold Wouldn't there be a compile time error if contravariance was the issue?

Comment: No, not in your code. Only if you'd try to return a typed expression like `Expression<Func<Customer,bool>>`.

Comment: @GertArnold So I'm pretty sure the contravariance point would be the same whether .NET or .NET Core. The code I've based this on works perfectly on 4.7 with EF 6 and the expression is deferred to the database server side. Why would contravariance be the issue for .NET Core with the exact same structure...EF translation issues aside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code work, you need to use a normal cast instead of safe cast.

The simplest way to accomplish this in your code is to do a double cast:

```cs
public class AssignedUserRecordAuthority : IRecordAuthority
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Clause<TEntity>() where TEntity : IEntity
    {
        if (typeof(TEntity) == typeof(Customer))
        {
            var name = _userService.ClaimsIdentity.Name;

            // Changed from `x as Customer` to `(Customer)(object)x`:
            return x => ((Customer)(object)x).ManagedBy == name; 
        }

        return x => false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked a treat. I knew there was a missing piece of the puzzle that would allow me to keep the structure. I think architecturally it's a sound and clean design. Do you know what actually led to the difference between EF6 and Core?

Comment: I updated the solution. Way more simpler now. Just add an intermediate cast to `object`. No need to change the method and interface signature etc. anymore.

Comment: Not completely sure why this differs between EF6 and EF Core, but EF Core is a full reimplementation. And technically, `x as Type` could return `null`, which couldn't really be handled in an easy way in the query pipeline, as far as I can see.